# Bootstrap responsiveness for Absolutely Positioned Elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 4 which is based on Flexbox. Now what happens if I position one of the columns or its subdivs absolutely? Would they respond to the responsiveness or not?

Example:

```
<div id="particles-js">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <img id="logo-small" src="img/logo-small.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div id="navigation-buttons">
                    <div class="nav-button"></div>
                    <div class="nav-button"></div>
                    <div class="nav-button"></div>
                    <div class="nav-button"></div>
                    <div class="nav-button"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, if I position the #navigation-buttons absolutely, and when the browser is resized the responsiveness is not working.

CSS

```
#particles-js {
        background-color: #252627;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    canvas {
        display: block;
    }

    #logo-small {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50vh;
    }

    #navigation-buttons {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50vh;
        width: 13px;
        top: 50vh;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -37%);
    }
```

P.S: #particles-js is a canvas

Comment: Absolute position elements follow their relative parent or body if relative parent is not available. They cannot be made responsive using bootstrap, you need to use media queries to change the properties of absolute positioned element to make them responsive.

Comment: @Niraj Thanks. So if I make a column relative and its subdiv absolute, what would actually happen on resizing? I would highly appreciate if you can make a CodePen if you have the time to do so! Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: your subdiv will be inside column if column has property relative.
you can view the first two video to get better understanding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kejG8G0dr5U&index=1&list=PLqGj3iMvMa4L731ispRfGAabXeRpM4RL6

Comment: you make the codepen i will help you in updating as per your need.

Comment: @Niraj Nitesh made a Fiddle but thanks a lot Niraj for answering. I watched the videos and yes i was wrong about the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to make parent as position:relative and now any child, you are making position absolute, it will be placed with respect to its parent position like in normal case**.
Having position absolute will just change position, it has nothing to do with responsiveness. It will behave as such how other code behaves using bootstrap classes.

Please check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="columns col-sm-4">
    First
    </div>
    <div class="columns col-sm-4">
    Second
    </div>
    <div class="columns col-sm-4 third">
    Third
    <div class="container test">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         Test1
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         Test2
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         Test3
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>    
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.third{
  position:relative;
}

.test{
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:-15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Exactly what I wanted to know. Actually I was confused and thought an absolute element is positioned according to the document's top always no matter if the parent is relative or not. One last thing to ask: I should avoid making columns absolute right? Because if one column is absolute and others not, the layout would mess up?

Comment: That depends, if you need a particular section that should be placed anywhere on the page then there is no harm in making layout with absolute position. 
I will say, bootstrap has no relation with making any element absolute or relative, it is just general CSS concept.